# Picard group of a normal crossing scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group, neron-severi-group

I would like to know if someone has an explicit example for the rank of the Neron-Severi group of a normal crossing scheme (proper over a field) being different from the rank of the kernel of $\operatorname{NS}(X^{(0)})\to \operatorname{NS}(X^{(1)})$, the restriction map from the Neron-Severi group of the components to the Neron-Severi group of its codimension 1 intersections.

In more sophisticated language: I'm interested in an explicit counterexamples to (rational) cdh-descent of the cohomology of 
$\mathbb{G}_m$ (over a finite field, so that up to finite groups $H^0(D,\mathbb{G}_m)=0$ and $H^1(D,\mathbb{G}_m)\cong \operatorname{NS}(D)$ 
for smooth and proper $D$).

An interesting example is a tetrahedron (i.e., four hyperplanes in
$\mathbb{P}^3$ in general position), where the rank of the kernel above
is one. Does anybody know how to calculate the Neron-Severi group of a tetrahedron?

Comment: The case of a tetrahedron $T\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ seems obvious to me: given a line bundle $L$ on $T$, its  restriction to each plane $P_i\subset T$ is of the form $\mathscr{O}_{P_i}(k_i)$, but restricting to $P_i\cap P_j$ gives $k_i=k_j$, so  the restriction  map $NS(\mathbb{P}^3)\rightarrow NS(T)$ is an isomorphism. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, this part of the question was easier than I thought.